# Show all discounts at checkout with Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, discounts

I've taken the difference between the actual price and sale price of items and created a variable to hold the total value to give me a total discount at my checkout. I am curious if there is a way to do this with less code though? If I try to show `{{ cart.totalDiscount | currency(cart.currency) }}` it just comes up as $0.00, and this is with promotions -> sales at 10% off for all products. If there is a simple snippet like the one I referenced I'd love to know about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, something else is at play here.

I use:

```
{% if cart.totalDiscount != 0 or cart.couponCode %}
  - {{ cart.totalDiscount | currency(cart.currency) }}
```

...and it works.

Are you sure the promotion is actually being applied?  I guess it is if you can calculate the discount.

Comment: Hmm, the promotion is applied for sure, I'll have to take another look I guess. Thanks for the feedback, I'll update if anything changes.